# Conditionally desctructure in union arguments

Tags: typescript

```
export type IVertex = {
  id: string
  name: string
}

export type IEdge = {
  source: string
  target: string
}
```

type.ts

```
  formatVertices (nodes: Array<IVertex>) {
    return nodes.map(node => {
      const { name, ...rest } = node
      return {
        data: { ...rest }
      }
    })
  }

  formatEdges (nodes: Array<IEdge>) {
    return nodes.map(node => ({ data: node }))
  }
```

How to refactor these methods into one?

I want to exclude `name` field in `IVertex` node. And I've tried adding `name` field in both nodes and destructure other fields, but still there's a type error.

```
formatNodes (nodes: Array<IVertex|IEdge>) {
    return nodes.map(node => {
      const { name, ...rest } = { node, name: '' }
      return {
        data: { ...rest }
      }
    })
  }
```

Sample: [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFAJwUwDwBwPYCcAu4UE85XASQGpSqzgC84A3hJOAJYAmAXOAM4pK0B2A5tZJwEMAtlGZsOPagF9Q1WIlTosOXAFF63HOSogarBAFckAY1Gt2XXrpooBSTSjEXJ1mWGvGEnNuABuRFFpTFmYCANgAbQBdMnAIvkoEyAZmAHIAQVSAGiTwQRE0gCkBYwBrVISpLJ09ZKZwVIAhbNz8s1SAJQQRCutIN0go2Q8vHygNKBC8dU1o2Pi%20xMXIFkMTdsyc5fQ7BzTmyq29GtrVo1M0gGEW7dt7KEcGgBFevQHwIfdwT280ADNkEIBChCKggpNYgAKTgIeiTZjpJBIAQYAA8YWIMAAfABKJZ6JAPIycPKwyYAOiBcGhZLIWPxtR%20PgoeWEUCy4HJXMJPiksRhcNyhJQxIZtXA9GBAmYLK55J5aHeb0qOOkw0gTP%20gOBMwh5BpcKmiORaLUE1xYvAwtFAopVINWnpkJZktszFt4CkONVrnV31GWqQQJQADlafrbUakSj0aCULAAD5mzQWk6Qa1IEmRykCake0j0tM0TWUVkiDlyhWe-lkoVEzOWvSu6WlyuTRW5JWen39IA)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NlpRxN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  If there is a type error, the code example should demonstrate it.

Comment: @jcalz demo added. Thanks!

Comment: Your demo is missing `=>` in a few places, but that's good enough for me to look at. Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NBPl4W) meet your needs?  If so, I can write up an answer.  Otherwise, please [edit] the example to demonstrate the failed use case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're just missing a spread on your `node` value.

I think this example accomplishes your goal

```
export type IVertex = {
  id: string
  name: string
}

export type IEdge = {
  source: string
  target: string
}

function formatNodes(nodes: Array<IVertex|IEdge>) {
  return nodes.map(node => {
    // note the `...node`
    const { name, ...rest } = { ...node, name: '' }
    return {
      data: { ...rest }
    }
  })
}
```